# Show Filename of next/prev images on back/forward button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm kinda new at web development, so am in need of professional helps.
I have a slideshow. The problem am facing is i want it to show filename of **next or previous images** on **back/forward icon** of the slideshow.
Is it possible? with these code.
Here is my briefing [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwE45.png)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
        <ul>
            <li><img src=""></li>
            <li><img src=""></li>       
        </ul>
        <span class="button prevButton"></span>
        <span class="button nextButton"></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(window).load(function(){
            var pages = $('#container li'), current=0;
            var currentPage,nextPage;

            $('#container .button').click(function(){
                currentPage= pages.eq(current);
                if($(this).hasClass('prevButton'))
                {

                    if (current <= 0)
                        current=pages.length-1;
                    else
                        current=current-1;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (current >= pages.length-1)
                        current=0;
                    else
                        current=current+1;
                }
                nextPage = pages.eq(current);   
                currentPage.hide(); 
                nextPage.show();        
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You do it kind of wrong way, you don't need to create element to every image that you have.

Also to get the filename use this code:

```
 url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

full code

```
<img src="" id="slide">    


$(window).load(function(){
        function getFileName(url) {
            return url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        }
        var $imgEl = $("#slide");
        var counter = 0;
        var imagesSrcs = [ 'http://www.exmaple.com/example.jpg', 'http://www.exmaple.com/example.jpg', 'http://www.exmaple.com/example.jpg']; 


        $('#container .button').click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('prevButton'))
            {

                counter--;
                if (counter < 0)
                    counter = imagesSrcs.length - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                counter++;
                if (counter == imagesSrcs.length)
                     counter = 0;

            }
            $imgEl.attr('src', imagesSrcs[counter]);
            console.log(getFileName(imagesSrcs[Math.min(counter + 1, imagesSrcs.length -1)])); //next image file name  
            console.log(getFileName(imagesSrcs[Math.max(counter - 1, 0)])); //previous image file name      
        });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u0fcbgga/

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your code, it's work like a normal slideshow, but i believe i have made you confused a bit, sorry about that. What i really want is i have this two back/forward button icon in that slideshow, and i like it to display of the next/prev image name before we click back/forward button
(this is there icon links https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWxOx.jpg )
and the result is a slideshow but it will go something like this
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR5pU.png)

p/s: Thank you for your hard work.